# Extracting number from file C++

Tags: c++, file, extract

In my program I want to extract a number from a line (which represents a stop time in seconds) from which I cut down another number that I extract from the next line (which represents a start time in seconds) and after that writing the result in the Results file.

I have the following code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <string>
# include <streambuf>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    ifstream f;
    ofstream g;
    f.open("Processes.txt");
    g.open("Results.txt");

    long last_el,top_nr=0,stop_nr=0,start_nr=0,stop_time_count=1,start_time_count=1,inter_count=0,global_count,final_result_count=1;
    long pow_start_nr=7,pow_stop_nr=7,stop_time[1000],start_time[1000],final_result[1000];
    string text_el;

    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << f.rdbuf();
    string str = strStream.str();
    
    last_el=text_el.size();
    
   // while(text.el)
   // {
       for(global_count=0;global_count<last_el;global_count++)
       {
          if(text_el[global_count]=='*')
          {
             inter_count=global_count+1;
             for(global_count=inter_count;global_count<=inter_count+7;global_count++)
             {
                start_nr=start_nr+(10^pow_start_nr)*text_el[global_count];
                pow_start_nr--;
             }
             start_time[start_time_count]=start_nr;
             start_time_count++;
             global_count=inter_count+8;
          }
       }

       for(global_count=0;global_count<last_el;global_count++)
       {
          if(text_el[global_count]=='#')
          {
             inter_count=global_count+1;
             for(global_count=inter_count;global_count<=inter_count+7;global_count++)
             {
                stop_nr=stop_nr+(10^pow_stop_nr)*text_el[global_count];
                pow_stop_nr--;
             }
                stop_time[stop_time_count]=stop_nr;
                stop_time_count++;
                global_count=inter_count+8;
             }
          }
  //  }

    for(final_result_count=1;final_result_count<2;final_result_count++)
    {
       final_result[final_result_count]=stop_time[stop_time_count]-start_time[start_time_count];
       stop_time_count++;
       start_time_count++;
       g<<"The time for process number"<<" "<< final_result_count <<" "<<"is"<<" "<< final_result[final_result_count] <<endl<<endl;
    }

    f.close();
    g.close();
}
```

In my exit file it is written just 0.

I don't know why this happens. I think there is something wrong with the text reading from the file.
There, with the " a " vector. I am noob with C++.

LE:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <string>
# include <sstream>
# include <streambuf>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    ifstream f;
    ofstream g;
    f.open("Processes.txt");
    g.open("Results.txt");
    
    long startTime[1000],endTime[1000];

    string nextLine;
    int lineNum = 1;

    while (getline(f, nextLine)) 
    {
        
    getline(f, nextLine);
    
    startTime[lineNum] = stoi(nextLine.substr(14,8));
    g<<startTime[lineNum]<<"xxxx";
    
    endTime[lineNum+1] = stoi(nextLine.substr(27,8));
    g<<endTime[lineNum]<<"xxxx";
    
    getline(f, nextLine);
    getline(f, nextLine);
    getline(f, nextLine);
    
    lineNum=lineNum+3;
    }

    f.close();
    g.close();
}
```

INPUT FILE:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
started at: *00000005  Number: 1
completed at: #00000065  Number: 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
started at: *00000000  Number: 2
completed at: #00000100  Number: 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
started at: *09999999  Number: 3
completed at: #10000000  Number: 3
```

Comment: Variable names are allowed to be longer than one character. If you for example change `d[1000]` into `final_results[1000]`, the program would be a lot easier to read.

Comment: Ok, i'll do that, thank you!

Comment: Buddy, Please write codes to follow C++ Coding Guideline. It's a good habit.

Comment: @Alexander there's no "C++ Coding Guidelines", but there certainly is common sense.

Comment: what do you expect `f >> n` to do when your input starts with `------`?

Comment: i tried to format your code, but its still a bit messy. Especially with the contents of your input and output file i was not sure (i mean I dont know what they really contain), maybe you can improve it even more, because it really matters what is the exact lines in the files (as you can see from previous comments)

Comment: I am currently changing the variables names to be more inteligible. The input file contains exactly what i posted and respects that pattern after " number 3" also. I cant change that, in that way i receive the file.

Regarding the expectations in wich concernes the f>>n thing, i said that there is the point that troubles me. I dont know if that wihile provides my program the entire information from the file.

Comment: how about instead of `started at: *<start>  Number: <nr> completed at: #<end> Number: <nr>` you output `<nr> <start> <end>`? then you could parse your lines like this: `while(f >> nr >> start >> end) { ... }`.

Comment: I receive the input file from my superior. I have to do a check and some calculations manually and this is why i decided to try to make my work easier with this program. I could ask him to make some minor changes.

Now, i think that what u said is really interesting and i dont have any knoledges on what u said there with " while(f >> nr >> start >> end) ". Could you explain more detailed please? I didnt even know that i cand put more than one ">>" thing. Isnt " >> " making the program to continue reading from the file?

Comment: Hei! I read around and i found that the best way is to put all info from the file in a string and then use just that string. 

I put this idea into the code, in the first post, i edited it. But it returns a error saying: "[Error] aggregate 'std::stringstream strStream' has incomplete type and cannot be defined".

How can i fix it? And after that, what do i write in that while so that he will read the string all the way, or i dont need it anymore? Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

As I believe your most recent comment states, you have found the best way to handle this. You want to read each line and parse the string. Something like follows:

```
std::string nextLine;
int lineNum = 0;

while (std::getline(f, nextLine)) {
    startTime[lineNum] = std::stol(nextLine.substr(14,8));
    endTime[lineNum] = std::stol(nextLine.substr(50,8));
    lineNum++;
}
```

Fair warning: I did not actually count those offsets carefully, so I might be off by a few. Also, you'll have to account for those "blank" lines of only dashes as well. But I'll leave you to the housekeeping.

Hope this puts you on the right path!

Comment: There are some strange functions in your code, but i think i understood it. You also skipped the part with the number construction, u simply "take" it as it is.

The question is, what do i do if the lenght of lines changes sometimes? I guess it wouldnt work with those particulary numbers..

Anyway, i think i got your point, i will dig up a little those substr and stol things.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there are different ways to parse the string. `stringstream`s also work well for parsing if your `string` is in a common pattern instead of at a common index offset. Also, `std::stol` is a C++11 feature, so if you don't have that, you'll have to recreate it yourself with `stringstream` -- only a 3 or so line function.

Comment: I have a dev 4.9.9 and when I compile its says that stol and readline aren t from std.I ve google it and it appears that you were right,they are.Why is that and what should I do?Is there something wrong with my compile?

LE: I ve just saw what you have written. Is there any way that I could insert those features in the compilers library?Isn t there some files so that I can put all my missing features?

Comment: I updated to Dev-C++ 5.11 and still missing features. :( Can u please point me out how can i recreate that with stringstream, please?

Comment: In a function:

`std::stringstream ss(nextLine);
long temp;
ss >> temp;
return temp;`

Comment: Omg, now it says: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Tell me what compiler should i use. Visual studio?

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio 2010. Now stol is accepted but the error appears on "readline", just like in Dev, it says that it isnt a std member.

Pff.. isnt there a substitute for this readline? :(

Comment: My mistake. The function should be `std::getline`.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 and 2013 cand run on my windows. I looked up on google and it said that i have to install Win 7 SP1 from microsoft. I did that, still saying "not compatible". I've reinstalled 2010, writed getline instead readline and wow, no errors, all good, BUT, i couldnt run the program, it said that my very created file was missing,

Comment: i searched it on goodle again, some guy (actually right from stackoverflow, thank u!) said that i have to delete some user file from my project. I did, when i run the program, no "missing file error" appeared, but the program doesent run, it doesent do anything. I writed a simple program to check this and still no runing, no output, I AM GOING MAD. :)))

PLEASE, tell me again what do i have to write in Dev to add that stol - std thing to features. I understood that a function, but where do i call it, what do i do with the thing that it returns? Its like, everything is going bad, omg..

Comment: You need two things: To compile using C++11: (use -std=c++11 in your compilation line), and to include the header file that defines these functions (`#include <string>;` or `#include <sstream>` or `#include <iostream>` depending on which function we are talking about).

Comment: Do u mean something like that? (look on the main post, i've add ed there, at the end.)
PS. it sais [Error] expected primary-expression before '=' token and [Error] 'c' was not declared in this scope. :(

Comment: No I mean the line that you use to compile with. As in `g++ filename -o programName -std=c++11` sort of thing

Comment: Oh, i got u now. I went to compiler options and put -std=c++11 in the field with "add the following comands when calling the linker" and "add the following comands when calling the compiler". When i compile now its all good, no errors, but if i run it it says: "Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'.

PS. At the linker format field i had also "-static-libgcc".
I tryed also to put -std=c++11 just in one of those two fields with the same result.

I dont really know, but it appears that the specific library isnt c++11 ?! Am i wrong? Correct me, please. :D

Comment: Yes now you are running it properly, but obviously some argument you are giving it is incorrect. Double check your arguments now and you should be good to go.

Comment: It doesent seem to me to be something wrong with the arguments. U can look yourself at the code (its in the main post, at the end, like i said).

Comment: Pfiu, i'll check it again tomorrow morning, with a "fresh head". Its kind of 00:00 on me now. :D "night!

Comment: 2 things I can think of: 1 => you are already `using namespace std`, so no need to call it as `std::stol`, just `stol`. 2 (probably the actual problem) => `lineNum` is just an int you defined so that you know what line number you're on. It doesn't just magically skip lines in your program. Therefore, you'll have to call `getline(f, nextLine)` twice every time you want to skip 2 lines. Try `cout`ing your variables and seeing if they are what you think you are and you'll figure this out.

Comment: I've updated again the code.
It says the same thing: " Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'. "
I think it still doesent recognise that stol.

Can u recomend me please another compiler? Other than Dev and Visual Studio. :(

Comment: I've made it!
I went with atoi function (similar to yours) and it works!

Thank you very much for your time, you really helped!